# Unexpected behavior when passing pointer to private variable

Tags: c++

Currently I am working a lot with GUI design where I am using a lot of callback methods. In general those methods looks like: `static void* Foo(void* data)`. Thanks to them I found out that I can access private variables without any issue just by passing their pointers.

Let say I have class like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        static void* Foo(void* data);

    private:
        int dummy_data = 3;
}
```

and methods:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    Foo((void*)&dummy_data);
}

void* MyClass::Foo(void* data)
{
    received_value = (int*)data;
    printf("Private value: %d\n",received_value);
}
```

And I can read `dumy_data` value. Normally if I would try to access this value compiler will rise error flag saying that this is private variable. And it doesn't matter if I'll pass it as a value, or pass pointer to my class and try to access this way.

So my question is - why is that happening? Yes, I know that I am passing pointer to value, but shouldn't compiler rise flag here as well?

Comment: If you think it has something to do with passing a pointer, did you try passing a not pointer?

Comment: @juanchopanza How you exactly see passing not pointer to method that requires pointer? It wouldn't compile, because parameters types are different.

Comment: @sebap123 You would change the signature of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `private` and `public` sections control visibility of the *names* declared in those sections. They don't control visibility of the *data*. Outside code cannot refer to the `MyClass::dummy_data` name because it's private. If the class chooses to expose the *value* of that variable somehow, or even the *address*, then that's the class's choice, and any code with access to that other avenue (a pointer, in this case) is free to read it. There is no language error present, so the compiler doesn't complain.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid.

Access restrictions are emplaced on the *names* of the members, not the members themselves. (Otherwise many getters would not work!)

A function that has been permitted (by being a member function) to access that member by name, has decided to pass along a pointer to that object. If you don't want that to happen, don't do it.

It would not actually be possible, in the general case, for the compiler to detect and block this code even if it were supposed to.